# Eclipse RCP Application not working on MacOS

Tags: nullpointerexception, eclipse-rcp, macos-big-sur

We have an old Eclipse RCP application (Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2) ) that is working on Windows and needs to be configured to work on MacOS

After adding missing plugins for MacOS the application returns a bunch of NullPointerException when trying to run the application in Debug mode (attached bellow). Also when we build the target and try to open it from the generated sources it gets stuck in the window where you select the workspace and you cannot click on any button or select anything

Setup:
Java:1.8.0_301
Eclispe: 4.4.2 Luna Service Release 2
MacOS: 11.5.2 Big Sur

Here is the most recent stack trace after I debug my app:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 2 2021-09-09 10:11:02.381
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.workbench".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.internal_new_GC(Control.java:2134)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.<init>(GC.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.<init>(GC.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.ProgressMonitorPart.initialize(ProgressMonitorPart.java:237)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.ProgressMonitorPart.<init>(ProgressMonitorPart.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.ProgressMonitorPart.<init>(ProgressMonitorPart.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.ui.splash.BasicSplashHandler$AbsolutePositionProgressMonitorPart.<init>(BasicSplashHandler.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.ui.splash.BasicSplashHandler.getBundleProgressMonitor(BasicSplashHandler.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.ui.splash.BasicSplashHandler.getContent(BasicSplashHandler.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.splash.EclipseSplashHandler.init(EclipseSplashHandler.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$6.run(Workbench.java:817)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createSplashWrapper(Workbench.java:839)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$5(Workbench.java:753)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2021-09-09 10:11:02.389
!MESSAGE Could not instantiate splash
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.internal_new_GC(Control.java:2134)
    ...

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2021-09-09 10:11:02.390
!MESSAGE Error occurred during status handling
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.StatusHandlerRegistry.<init>(StatusHandlerRegistry.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.StatusHandlerRegistry.getDefault(StatusHandlerRegistry.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.getStatusHandler(StatusManager.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.handle(StatusManager.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.handle(StatusManager.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.handle(StatusManager.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$6.handleException(Workbench.java:829)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.handleException(SafeRunner.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createSplashWrapper(Workbench.java:839)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$5(Workbench.java:753)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
2021-09-09 10:11:03.698 java[3553:504839] *** WARNING: Method userSpaceScaleFactor in class NSView is deprecated on 10.7 and later. It should not be used in new applications. Use convertRectToBacking: instead. 

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2021-09-09 10:11:05.046
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.internal_new_GC(Control.java:2134)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.<init>(GC.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.<init>(GC.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressManagerUtil.shortenText(ProgressManagerUtil.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressViewerLabelProvider.getText(ProgressViewerLabelProvider.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressCanvasViewer$2.paintControl(ProgressCanvasViewer.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4199)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1467)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1490)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1475)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.drawWidget(Control.java:1244)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.drawWidget(Canvas.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.drawRect(Widget.java:749)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.drawRect(Canvas.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5616)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationNextEventMatchingMask(Display.java:5000)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationProc(Display.java:5378)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSend(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSApplication.nextEventMatchingMask(NSApplication.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3663)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2021-09-09 10:11:05.051
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to execute runnable (java.lang.NullPointerException)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4441)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4356)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3994)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3671)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.internal_new_GC(Control.java:2134)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.<init>(GC.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.<init>(GC.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.updateTabHeight(CTabFolder.java:3717)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.runUpdate(CTabFolder.java:3752)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder$10.run(CTabFolder.java:3741)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:136)
```

The plugins that I’m using in the product file:

```
<plugins> 
      <plugin id="com.google.guava"/>
      <plugin id="com.google.inject"/>
      <plugin id="com.ibm.icu"/>
      <plugin id="javax.annotation"/>
      <plugin id="javax.inject"/>
      <plugin id="javax.servlet"/>
      <plugin id="javax.xml"/>
      <plugin id="lpg.runtime.java"/>
      <plugin id="org.antlr.runtime"/>
      <plugin id="org.apache.ant"/>
      <plugin id="org.apache.batik.css"/>
      <plugin id="org.apache.batik.util"/>
      <plugin id="org.apache.batik.util.gui"/>
      <plugin id="org.apache.commons.cli"/>
      <plugin id="org.apache.commons.lang"/>
      <plugin id="org.apache.commons.logging"/>
      <plugin id="org.apache.log4j"/>
      <plugin id="org.apache.lucene.analysis"/>
      <plugin id="org.apache.lucene.core"/>
      <plugin id="org.apache.xerces"/>
      <plugin id="org.apache.xml.resolver"/>
      <plugin id="org.apache.xml.serializer"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ant.core"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ant.launching"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ant.ui"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.compare"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.compare.core"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.compare.win32"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.commands"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.contenttype"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.databinding"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.databinding.beans"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.databinding.property"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.expressions"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.externaltools"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.filebuffers"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.filesystem"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.filesystem.java7" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.filesystem.macosx" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.jobs"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.net"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.resources"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.runtime"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.registry" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.variables"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.debug.core"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.debug.ui"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.draw2d"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.core.commands"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.core.di"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.core.di.extensions"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.core.services"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.di"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.workbench"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.services"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.widgets"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.cocoa" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.cocoa.source"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.source"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench3"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.codegen"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.ui"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ui"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.common"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.common.ui"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.compare"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.compare.edit"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.compare.ide"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.compare.ide.ui"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.compare.rcp"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.compare.rcp.ui"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.ecore"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.ecore.change"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.ecore.change.edit"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.ecore.edit"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.ecore.editor"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.edit"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.edit.ui"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.mapping.ecore2xml"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.mwe.utils"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.lib"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.runtime"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.query"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.query.ocl"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.search"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.search.common"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.search.ecore"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.search.ui"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.transaction"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.validation"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.validation.ui"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.validation.ui.ide"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.workspace"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.app"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.bidi"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.common"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.ds"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.event"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.frameworkadmin"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.frameworkadmin.equinox"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.launcher"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director.app"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.garbagecollector"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.jarprocessor"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.eclipse"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.tools"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.eclipse"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.updatesite"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.preferences"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.region" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.registry"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.security"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.security.macosx" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.security.macosx.source"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.security.ui"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.manipulator"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.transforms.hook" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.util"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.hook" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.help"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.help.base"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.help.ui"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jdt"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jdt.annotation"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jdt.compiler.apt" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jdt.compiler.tool" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jdt.core"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.manipulation"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jdt.debug"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jdt.junit"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jdt.junit.core"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jdt.junit.runtime"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jdt.launching"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.macosx"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.ui.macosx"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jdt.ui"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jem.util"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jetty.continuation"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jetty.http"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jetty.io"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jetty.security"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jetty.server"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jetty.servlet"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jetty.util"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jface"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jface.databinding"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jface.text"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ocl"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ocl.common"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ocl.common.ui"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ocl.ecore"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ocl.ecore.edit"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ocl.edit"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ocl.examples"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ocl.examples.codegen"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ocl.examples.codegen.asm3"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ocl.examples.codegen.asm5"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ocl.examples.common"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ocl.examples.debug"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ocl.examples.debug.vm"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ocl.examples.domain"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ocl.examples.emf.validation.validity"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ocl.examples.emf.validation.validity.ui"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ocl.examples.eventmanager"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ocl.examples.impactanalyzer"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ocl.examples.impactanalyzer.util"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ocl.examples.interpreter"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ocl.examples.library"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ocl.examples.modelregistry"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ocl.examples.modelregistry.edit"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ocl.examples.modelregistry.editor"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ocl.examples.modelregistry.ui"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ocl.examples.pivot"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ocl.examples.ui"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ocl.examples.xtext.base"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ocl.examples.xtext.base.ui"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ocl.examples.xtext.completeocl"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ocl.examples.xtext.completeocl.ui"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ocl.examples.xtext.console"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ocl.examples.xtext.essentialocl"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ocl.examples.xtext.essentialocl.ui"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ocl.examples.xtext.markup"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ocl.examples.xtext.markup.ui"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ocl.examples.xtext.oclinecore"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ocl.examples.xtext.oclinecore.ui"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ocl.examples.xtext.oclstdlib"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ocl.examples.xtext.oclstdlib.ui"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ocl.ui"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ocl.uml"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ocl.uml.edit"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ocl.uml.ui"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.osgi"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.osgi.services"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.osgi.util"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.pde.build"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.pde.core"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.pde.launching"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.pde.ui"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.platform"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.rcp"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.search"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.team.core"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.team.ui"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.text"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ui"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ui.cheatsheets"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ui.cocoa" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ui.cocoa.source"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ui.console"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ui.editors"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ui.externaltools"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ui.forms"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ui.ide"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ui.ide.application"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ui.intro"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ui.navigator"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ui.net"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ui.trace"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ui.views"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ui.views.log"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.tabbed"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ui.workbench"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.uml2.codegen.ecore"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.uml2.common"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.uml2.common.edit"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.uml2.types"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.uml2.uml"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.uml2.uml.edit"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.uml2.uml.profile.standard"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.uml2.uml.resources"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.update.configurator"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.wst.common.core"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.wst.common.emf"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.wst.common.environment"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.wst.common.uriresolver"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.wst.sse.core"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.wst.validation"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.wst.xml.core"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.wst.xsd.core"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.xsd"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.xtend"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.xtend.lib"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.xtend.lib.macro"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.xtend.typesystem.emf"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.xtext"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.xtext.builder"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.xtext.common.types"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.xtext.common.types.edit"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.xtext.common.types.ui"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.xtext.ecore"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.xtext.smap"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.xtext.ui"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.xtext.ui.ecore"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.xtext.ui.shared"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.xtext.util"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.lib"/>
      <plugin id="org.hamcrest.core"/>
      <plugin id="org.junit"/>
      <plugin id="org.objectweb.asm"/>
      <plugin id="org.sat4j.core"/>
      <plugin id="org.sat4j.pb"/>
      <plugin id="org.slf4j.api"/>
      <plugin id="org.w3c.css.sac"/>
      <plugin id="org.w3c.dom.events"/>
      <plugin id="org.w3c.dom.smil"/>
      <plugin id="org.w3c.dom.svg"/>
   </plugins>
```

And the target.target file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?pde version="3.8"?><target name="MDESP2018 Target" sequenceNumber="114">
<locations>
<location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="planner" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
<unit id="org.eclipse.sdk.ide" version="4.4.2.M20150204-1700"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.sdk.feature.group" version="3.10.2.v20150204-1316"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group" version="4.4.2.v20150204-1700"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.releng.tools.feature.group" version="3.5.1.v20140604-1105"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.platform.sdk" version="4.4.2.M20150204-1700"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.rcp.source.feature.group" version="4.4.2.v20150204-1700"/>
<repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.4"/>
</location>
<location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="planner" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
<unit id="org.eclipse.ocl.examples.feature.group" version="3.4.4.v20150213-2254"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.emf.compare.ide.ui.feature.group" version="3.0.2.201501201328"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.emf.diffmerge.sdk.feature.feature.group" version="0.3.0.v20140611-1329"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.ocl.all.sdk.feature.group" version="5.0.2.v20141027-1335"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature.feature.group" version="3.6.3.v201501292352"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.emf.query.sdk.feature.group" version="1.8.0.201405281426"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.emf.validation.sdk.feature.group" version="1.8.0.201405281429"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.emf.compare.feature.group" version="3.0.2.201501201328"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.emf.sdk.feature.group" version="2.10.2.v20150123-0452"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.emf.transaction.sdk.feature.group" version="1.8.0.201405281451"/>
<repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna"/>
</location>
<location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="planner" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
<unit id="org.eclipse.emf.search.codegen.feature.group" version="0.7.0.v200806130939"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.emf.search.ecore.feature.group" version="0.7.0.v200806130939"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.emf.search.runtime.feature.group" version="0.7.0.v200806130939"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.emf.search.doc.feature.group" version="0.7.0.v200806130939"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.emf.search.common.feature.group" version="0.7.0.v200806130939"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.emf.search.feature.group" version="0.7.0.v200806130939"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.emf.search.sdk.feature.group" version="0.7.0.v200806130939"/>
<repository location="https://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emft/updates/releases/"/>
</location>
<location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="planner" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
<unit id="org.junit" version="4.11.0.v201303080030"/>
<unit id="org.apache.log4j" version="1.2.15.v201012070815"/>
<repository location="http://archive.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20140525021250/repository/"/>
</location>
</locations>
</target>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like Eclipse bug [434393](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=434393).

The bug is marked as fixed in Eclipse 4.5 so you will need to move to at least that release.

However older versions of Eclipse have various UI display issues on macOS 11 so if you are changing versions you should move to the current Eclipse 4.20 (soon to be 4.21)